# Windows: Where are the executables of apps installed from Store?

Tags: windows, windows-10, path, windows-store-app, file-location

I installed an app from Windows Store. Now I want to pass its path (location) to **another app** (like `Run` window) to run it in response to an event:

[image]

But it doesn't exist in `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` and its shortcut (in Start menu or on Desktop) hasn't an option to *open file location*.

[image]

When I try `Open file location` by right-clicking on the process name in Task Manager:

[image]

Then encounter to permission problem (though the user is administrator):

[image]

And if I repeat the process, but from `Details` tab (of Task Manager):

[image]

Finally, I see a related executable file in Windows Explorer. But when try to open it directly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP type app no exe file like classic application. It's app package. You can read this article to understand it well.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

Answer (score 4):

UWP Apps such as Xbox Companion and others downloaded from the Windows Store do have an EXE, in fact some even have two or more. There’s a run command that opens a file explorer windows showing all the apps and you can even set as desktop shortcuts but copy and pasting them.

The file path to UWP apps has the `hidden` attribute in Program Files, which you would need to set the ability to see such files/folders via Folder Explorer Options. Then in the root of your C you should see a translucent like folder icon labeled `Program Files\WindowsApps`

Comment: This is a better and more complete and accurate answer than either OPs answer/comment or the accepted answer.

Comment: You also need to jump through some hoops to get permission to browse that folder.

Answer (score 2):

Pass shortcut's path to the runner (e.g. `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\AppShortcut.lnk`). This worked and my problem solved. *But I didn't understand where is main executable!*

Comment: You actually DO understand where the main executable is, given that your screenshot shows that you found it. Its just that the APP model requires launching it through the framework, which is why the target is a weird string, followed by !app. Windows 10 understands this and launches the correct way to run the app. That's also why security measures are in place trying to prevent you from accessing it. Sort of anti hack attempt from Microsoft. That's all that matters.

Comment: The main executable is probably a runner that Windows has. UWP apps aren't apps - they're instructions for the runner to execute. So there is no EXE, the shortcut just starts the runner and points it to the application. Correct me if I'm wrong, I haven't used UWP apps and this is just a guess.

Comment: My challenge was getting this to open from Firefox's file handler. This answer got me most of the way there. Firefox cannot select the *.lnk file as a handler. In addition, I created a `runfile.cmd` file with the contents `start "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Application.lnk" "%1"`